# Perl: Hash ref accessing array of keys

Tags: perl, hash

I have a question that seems basic, but I can't figure out. Say that I have a hash reference in Perl. I want to get an array of values through an array of keys.

Here's how it'd work with a hash, not a hash reference:

```
my %testHash = ( "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 );
my @testKeys = ("a", "b", "c");

my @testValues = @testHash{@testKeys};
```

Now suppose I have a hash reference,

```
my $hashRef = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3};
```

I've tried the following two ways:

```
my @values = @{$hashRef->{@testKeys}};
my @values = $hashRef->{@testKeys};
```

But neither is correct. Is there a correct way, or do I just have to dereference the hash ref every time I want to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're close:

```
my @values = @$hashref{@testKeys};     ## (1)
```

or

```
my @values = @{$hashref}{@testKeys};   ## (2)
```

For more examples, see ["Slices" in the perllol documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html#Slices).

["Using References" in the perlref documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) gives the general rules.

> 1. Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a simple scalar variable containing a reference of the correct type.

This explains why (1) works: you replaced the identifier `testHash` with the simple scalar `$hashRef`.

> 2. Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a BLOCK returning a reference of the correct type.

Snippet (2) above is nearly the same but has a little bulkier syntax. In place of the identifier `testHash`, you write a block returning a reference to a hash, *i.e.*, `{$hashRef}`.

The braces here enclose a *bona fide* block, so you can compute and return a reference, as in

```
push @{ $cond ? \@a1 : \@a2 }, "some value";
```

Comment: In this case, `@$hashref{@testKeys}` works too.  I used to prefer `{}` braces as more explicit, but I'd lean towards the less noisy variant now.

Comment: @ephemient Thanks for helping me improve the answer.

Comment: Ahh, I guess I was trapped by my lack of understanding that the arrow is just a convenient shorthand.

Comment: Just so I can understand the use of the arrow better, is there a way to do this with the arrow? It seems that @$hashRef->{@testKeys} should work, but it doesn't. I think there's an issue with order of precedence of the operators.

Comment: @user864684 The same perlref section describes arrows as syntactic sugar: "3. Subroutine calls and **lookups of individual array elements** ..." A slice looks up multiple elements, so the arrow syntax doesn't apply.