# Perl sql query statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl

My sql statement is simple as below:

```
if not exists (select col_a from t_a where co_b = 'v_b')
begin
    insert into t_a (col_a  ,col_b  ) 
        VALUES(v_a,v_b)
end
else
begin
    update t_a set col_a = v_a, col_b = v_b where col_b = 'v_b'
end
```

As I have hundreds of rows to update, how can I do this in Perl for the least time cost?

If I use Prepare + Execute, how to write the statement using the placeholder `?` ?

Does the `$dbh->prepare($statement);` support multiple composite SQL lines like those above? Or do I have to save the lines into an sql file and run it using SQL server?

To make the question more clear, my Perl lines look like those below:

```
$statement = "if ... VALUES(?,?)...update t_a set col_a = ?, col_b = ?"; 
# better to use one binding values(v_a, v_b) couplets mapping 
# the 2 placeholders of insert and update both?
foreach (@$va_arr) {
    my $values_for_one_row = $_;            
    $dbh->prepare($statement);
    $execute->execute($values_for_one_row->{col_a }, $values_for_one_row->{col_b });
}
```

I forgot one thing: the 'whatever' is also a value in $va_arr to be changed on every iteration: if not exists (select col_a from t_a where co_b = 'v_b'). Also, the update section should be: update t_a set col_a = ?, col_b = ? where col_b = "v_b". Seems no better way then include the prepare into the loop? Sorry I didn't think the example complete. But I think simbabque's answer is good enough.

Comment: The DBI supports running single SQL statements per call to `execute`. This looks like a single statement to me. You should read up in the [documentation of DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your words clearly. My statement have some if-else logic better handled by the SQL server engine. I didn't expect  to include the logic into Perl lines. I heard prepare is expensive considering I have hundreds of rows every time calling in the @$va_arr to loop.

Comment: You are right about that. Please see my answer below.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Are you able to ["upsert" via MERGE](http://www.sergeyv.com/blog/archive/2010/09/10/sql-server-upsert-equivalent.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your SQL without problems. You need to prepare the statement once. I am assuming your `$va_arr` looks like this:

```
my $va_arr = [
  {
    col_a => 1,
    col_b => 2,
  },
  {
    col_a => 'foo',
    col_b => 'bar',
  },
];
```

Your code to run this could be as follows. **Note that you have to pass the `col_n` params twice** as it needs to fill them in two times into each `?` with every execute. They get filled in the order of the `?` in the query, so we need `col_a`, `col_b` for the `INSERT` and another `col_a`, `col_b` for the `UPDATE`.

```
my $sql = <<'EOSQL';
if not exists (select col_a from t_a where co_b = 'whatever')
begin
    insert into t_a (col_a  ,col_b  ) 
        VALUES(?, ?)
end
else
begin
    update t_a set col_a = ?, col_b = ?
end
EOSQL

my $sth = $dbi->prepare($sql);
foreach ($values = @{ $va_arr }) {
  $dbh->execute($values->{col_a }, $values->{col_b }, 
                $values->{col_a }, $values->{col_b });
}
```

---

If you have a long list of columns and you know the order, consider this:

```
my @columns = qw( col_a col_b col_c col_n );
my $va_arr = [
  {
    col_a => 1,
    col_b => 2,
    col_n => 99,
  },
  {
    col_a => 'foo',
    col_b => 'bar',
    col_n => 'baz',
  },
];

# build the sql dynamically based on columns
my $sql = q{
if not exists (select col_a from t_a where co_b = 'whatever')
begin
    insert into t_a (} . join(',' @columns) . q{) 
        VALUES(} . join(',', map '?', @columns) . q{)
end
else
begin
    update t_a set } . join(',' map { "$_ => ?" } @columns) . q{
end
};
my $sth = $dbi->prepare($sql);
foreach ($values = @{ $va_arr }) {
  $dbh->execute(@{$values}{@columns}, @{$values}{@columns});
}
```

Let's look at what this does. It's helpful if you have a really long list of columns.

- You know their names and order, and put that into `@columns`.
- Build the SQL based on these columns. We have to add the column name and a `?` to the `INSERT` and the combination of both to the `UPDATE` for each of the columns.
- Execute it with a [hash ref slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131568/1331451)

Please note that I have not run this, just hacked it in here.

Comment: I forgot one thing: the 'whatever' is also a value in $va_arr to be changed on every iteration: if not exists (select col_a from t_a where co_b = 'v_b'). Also, the update section should be: update t_a set col_a = ?, col_b = ? where col_b = "v_b". Seems no better way then include the prepare into the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I got this. If the query changes (meaning the left side of `=` or `like`), you need to reprepare it. If you just have a variable on the right side of a condition, you can put a `?` there and do not need to reprepare.

Comment: Forget that. For another issue: in fact, as I had tried, the execute function should be called like this: $dbh->execute($values->{col_a }, $values->{col_b }, $values->{col_a }, $values->{col_b }); The binding value should be listed one by one, even they're repeated in Insert and Update the same sequence. Or the Perl interpreter will report error pointing out the number of placeholder and the binding values are not match.

Comment: Ah, damn it. Of course you need to put them in two times. I forgot that, will add it now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the prepare statement out of the loop and use a transaction

for example:

```
my $sql1 = qq(select col_a from t_a where col_b = ?);
my $sql2 = qq(insert into t_a (col_a, col_b) VALUES(?, ?));
my $sql3 = qq(update t_a set col_a = ? where col_b = ?);

my $query = $dbh->prepare($sql1);

$dbh->begin_work();

foreach (@$va_arr) {

    my $values_for_one_row = $_;
    $query->execute($values_for_one_row->{col_b});
    my @out = $query->fetchrow_array();
    $query->finish();

    if ( not defined $out[0] )
      {
        $dbh->do($sql2, undef, $values_for_one_row->{col_a}, $values_for_one_row->{col_b});
      }
      else
      {
        $dbh->do($sql3, undef, $values_for_one_row->{col_a}, $values_for_one_row->{col_b});
      }
}

$dbh->commit();
```

Comment: Your comment about `prepare` outside the loop is good, but why did you break up the logic the OP has in his SQL query? The SQL Server is able to optimize this, so there is no need to do additional queries. Also, using `do` will `prepare` each time inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If upsert is not available, here's how I might do it:

1. Bulk load the data into a staging table.
2. Delete all data that joins to the target table.
3. Insert data from staging to target.

Alternatively you can update from staging to target, delete from the staging data that joins, then insert what's left in staging.

Or, a few hundred rows is not that many, so I might: prepare an insert and an update statement handle outside of the loop. Then in the loop:

```
my $rows = $upd_sth->execute(...);
$ins_sth->execute(...) if $rows == 0;
```