# Initialize a set of hash keys using slicing in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to initialize a hash using slicing:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my %h;
my $a=['a','b'];

@h{@$a}=(1)x@$a;
dump(%h);
```

This works fine, but if I try to do a sub hash, for example `%h{test}`

```
@h{test}{@$a}=(1)x@$a;
```

I get error:

```
Scalar value @h{test} better written as $h{test} at ./p.pl line 14.
syntax error at ./p.pl line 14, near "}{"
Execution of ./p.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: `%h{test}` makes no sense. Do you mean the hash referenced by `$h{test}`? That would be `%{ $h{test} }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `@{ $h{test} }{ @$a }=(1)x@$a;` since hash contains hash reference, not hash.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h;
my $a=['a','b'];

@{ $h{test} }{ @$a }=(1)x@$a;
print Dumper(\%h);
```

Output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'test' => {
                      'a' => 1,
                      'b' => 1
                    }
        };
```

See also: [Perl: Hash ref accessing array of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131541/perl-hash-ref-accessing-array-of-keys)

Comment: Thanks Vadim. This works, but the syntax confuses me :)

Comment: See the link I provided. Syntax is not simple, but actually clean and understandable. I still use docs every time I do such things though ;).

Comment: the syntax is simple if presented properly; see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: @ysth True, I personally like to use `map`. `%{ $h{test} } = map { $_ => 1 } @$a`

Comment: Or even more explicit `$h{test}->{$_} = 1 foreach @$a;`

Comment: @VadimPushtaev that's the beauty of `perl`

Answer (score -1):

The compiler sees the '@' and thinks to itself 'array', then sees the '{' and says 'wait, what? that's a hash index indicator. Game over man.' So turn the @ into a $.

Comment: Well, it's not going to work since `@$a` will be used in scalar context and you get `$h{test}{2} = (a,b)`.

Comment: That's as may be, but that isn't what the compiler was complaining about.

Comment: I believe it's not about valid syntax, it's about getting things done. Empty string is perfect valid perl program, but OP doesn't want it :).